# How to display MySQL data in JTable without using vector?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to display MySQL data in JTable without using vector?

I'm doing Java Swing application and I want to show reports from database. I'm using `JTable` to display data from database. I have tried following code but it is not displaying data from database.  My database connection is also correct.

```
int i;
static Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

String[] columnNames = {"Registration id", "First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Address", "Dob", "Age", "Date Of Registration", "Register Rfid No."};
public AdmissionReport()
{
    initComponents();

    //this is the model which contain actual body of JTable
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
    //jTable1=new JTable(model);
    jTable1 = new JTable();
    jTable1.setModel(model);
    int i1 = jTable1.getRowCount();
    if (i1 > 1) {
        model.removeRow(0);
        i1 = i1 - 1;
    }

    String str = "select rid,fname,mname,lname,address,dob,age,dor,rfidtagdata from schoolrfid.registration";
    Connection cn;
    ResultSet rs;
    Statement st;

    String rid, fname, mname, lname, add, dob, age, dor, rfidtag;

    try {
        // Change the database name, hosty name,
        // port and password as per MySQL installed in your PC.
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + "localhost:3306/schoolrfid", "root", "root");
        st = cn.createStatement();

        rs = st.executeQuery(str);
        System.out.println("connected to database.. ");
        // int i=0;
        while (rs.next()) {

            //Vector <String> d=new Vector<String>();
            rid = (rs.getString("rid"));
            fname = (rs.getString("fname"));
            mname = (rs.getString("mname"));
            lname = (rs.getString("lname"));
            add = (rs.getString("address"));
            dob = (rs.getString("dob"));
            age = (rs.getString("age"));
            dor = (rs.getString("dor"));
            rfidtag = (rs.getString("rfidtagdata"));

            i = 0;
            String[] data = {rid, fname, mname, lname, add, dob, age, dor, rfidtag};

            model.addRow(data);
            i++;

        }
        if (i < 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Record Found", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            System.out.println(i + " Record Found");
        } else {
            System.out.println(i + " Records Found");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485987/how-to-add-items-to-a-jtable-using-a-loop

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). Hard code some data to replace the DB.  2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: @user3079393 dont forget to mark it as answer and cast your upvote if it satisfies your requirement

Answer (score 2):

The `TableModel` behind the `JTable` handles all of the data behind the table.  In order to add and remove rows from a table, you need to use a `DefaultTableModel`

To create the table with this model:

```
JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Column1", "Column2"}));
```

**To add a row:**

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
model.addRow(new Object[]{"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"});
```

You can also remove rows by `removeRow(int row)` which will removes the row at row from the model.

Full details on the DefaultTableModel can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

---

Similarly from the MySQL you can add rows like as show below

```
DefaultTableModel memberTable = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
while(rs.next())
{
    memberTable.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString('rid'),rs.getString('fname'),rs.getString('lname'),rs.getString('address'),.....});
}
```

---

Also Take a look at this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17655017/1575570